# Random Data Analyzer

Tags: java

I'm creating a program that will generate 100 random numbers between 1 and 1000, add them to a list, and then sum up those numbers. Here's my code:

```
public class Iteration {

    public static void main (String [] args){


    private int RandomDataAnalyzer(int Rando) { 

        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Integer> NumList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0;i<=100;i++){
        Rando = rand.nextInt(1001);
        NumList.add(Rando);

        }

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            Rando = rand.nextInt(100);
            sum = sum + Rando;
        }

        return sum;
        }


    }

}
```

And here's my errors:

```
H:\Java\Iteration.java:12: error: illegal start of expression
    private int RandomDataAnalyzer(int Rando) {

    ^
H:\Java\Iteration.java:12: error: ';' expected
    private int RandomDataAnalyzer(int Rando) { 
                                  ^
H:\Java\Iteration.java:12: error: ';' expected
    private int RandomDataAnalyzer(int Rando) {
```

Any help, please?

Comment: You can't define a method inside another method.

Comment: And on top of that you are summing up new random numbers not the ones from the collection as per your requirement: `sum up those numbers`

Comment: You should read up about Java naming conventions: methods and variables tend to start with lowercase letters. There also isn't much point in passing `Rando` as a parameter, you never use the value that is passed in. Also, this generates 101 random numbers, but sums only 100 of them - or at least, it would if it weren't regenerating the random numbers in the second loop.

Comment: Also, your random calls don't meet your requirements either.  `Rando = rand.nextInt(1001);` generates a random number between 0 and 1000, `Rando = rand.nextInt(100);` generates a random number between 0 and 99. Also, your first `for` loop generates 101 random numbers.

Comment: As you are just starting out to code, it would be good to have a look at naming conventions. For instance it is common in Java to use CamelCase. Variables start lowercase (example `Random randomGenerator = new Random();`) while classes, interfaces, enums etc start uppercase (example `RandomDataAnalyzer`). It may not seem significant at the moment, but it is really helping you to produce code that is more readable to you and to other programmers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a method inside another method. Close your `main` method first, then start `RandomDataAnalyzer`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Contents of main.
}

public int RandomDataAnalyzer(int Rando) {
  // Contents of RandomDataAnalyzer.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version. Note the changes to your original:

- Don't define methods inside methods: it is illegal syntax.
- `Rando`, `NumList`: the naming conventions are to start classes, interfaces, enums (i.e. types) with a capital letter, and methods, fields, and variables with a lowercase case letter;
- Removed the `int Rando` parameter alltogether: it's value was never used (it was only assigned to)
- Use the values from `numList` rather than generating *new* numbers.
- Added a method illustrating that the use of such a list is not needed in this case; the 'list' of 1000 numbers is still present, but only conceptually.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Iteration {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int sum = new Iteration().randomDataAnalyzer();
        System.out.println(sum);
    }


    private int randomDataAnalyzer() { 
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for ( int i=0; i<100; i++ )
        {
            numList.add( 1 + rand.nextInt(1000) );
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for ( int i=0; i<numList.size(); i++ )
        {
            sum = sum + numList.get(i);
        }

        return sum;
    }

    // Note that the above method has the same effect as this one:
    private int moreEfficient() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int sum = 0;
        for ( int i=0; i < 100; i++)
            sum += 1 + rand.nextInt(1000);
        return sum;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please can you mark the changes to the original, rather than making us hunt? It is hard to locate the changes when they're not side-by-side.

Comment: I'd say this is a version that *compiles*, not necessarily one that is working as specified (see comments on question).

Comment: @AndyTurner It also runs! ;-) You're right, it generated 101 numbers between 0 and 1000. Other than that it was working properly (even with the redundant number generation).

Comment: *it compiles* and *it runs* doesn't mean that it works. It might well do now that you have completely rewritten your answer, though.

Comment: 1) I've updated the answer *because of your comments*. 2) You can simply run my previous version to see that it works (click 'edit' and select the previous revision).

Comment: I looked at your last version: it put 101 random numbers in a list (not 100, as specified in the question), and it didn't sum the numbers in the list (as specified in the question), but instead generated 100 more random numbers and summed those. I reiterate: compiling and running isn't the same as working.

Comment: I reiterate my earlier comment: *"You're right, it generated 101 numbers between 0 and 1000. Other than that it was working properly (even with the redundant number generation)."*. Maybe you don't understand what I meant with my last bulletpoint "*Added a method illustrating that the use of such a list is not needed in this case; the 'list' of 1000 numbers is still present, but only conceptually."*?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that this isn't a homework problem and that you're learning Java on your own. If I'm wrong, shame on me for giving a working version. But my impression is that you'll learn from this:

```
public class gpaCalc 
{
    static Random rand;
    static int rando;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> NumList = new ArrayList<>(); // use ArrayList

        for (int i=0;i<=100;i++)
        {
          rand = new Random();
          rando = rand.nextInt(1001);
          NumList.add(rando);
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            rando = NumList.get(i); // get is "opposite" of put--get the value put into the list earlier
            sum = sum + rando;
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be a need for a separate method called `randomDataAnalyzer`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Let's begin with the first issue: `randomDataAnalyzer` is being defined inside `main` method. Which is wrong, you should be actually defining it at the same level.
Taken into consideration, you should also add the `static` word before this function because this method is part of the class, and not of the elements. It's not necessary to create a new element of the class 'Iteration' for using a simple method.
Last, but not least, you are looping through the arraylist incorrectly. You are not even calling it. As you will see now:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Iteration
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<int> numberList = new ArrayList<int>(); // we define the arraylist
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            numberList.add(new Random().nextInt(1001)); // we add a random number to the list
        }
        // finally, after the 100 values were added..
        System.out.println(randomDataAnalyzer(numberList)); // we show the output
    }

    public static int randomDataAnalyzer(ArrayList<int> list) // we will send this function an arraylist which will get the Σ.
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int value : list) // this is how we loop through foreach value in the list
        {
            sum += value; // which means sum = sum + value.
        }
        return sum; // after looping and summing up, here'll be the result
    }
}
```

I hope this was what you were looking for.